# событие onblur отрабатывает не корректно

Tags: jquery

```
email.onblur = function() {
        validate_data('email',$('#email').val(),0);
        $('#email').mailgun_validator({
                api_key: 'key',
                in_progress: validation_in_progress, // called when request is made to validator
                success: validation_success,         // called when validator has returned
                error: validation_error,           // called when an error reaching the validator has occured
        });

};
```

есть такой код по проверке email, первая функция пользовательская, вторая анонимная из библиотеки.В данном случае email это id инпута. Пример взят отсюда: [ссылка1](https://learn.javascript.ru/focus-blur) Проблема в том что, когда первый раз убираешь фокус срабатывает только первая функция, когда же делаешь все повторно уже две функции отрабатывают. В чем проблема?

**UPD** полный код вызова: просто обернут в `$(document).ready(function () { });`Используется библиотека mailgun, jquery плагин. Документация тут [ссылка](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-email-validation.html)

Comment: `onblur` тут абсолютно не причем. наверное вы где нибудь в модалке это делаете, а модальное аяксом подтягиваете..... надо `unbind` события делать....надо б код весь посмотреть, в т.ч. происходит это в доп. окне или нет

Comment: вызова, + код в котором данный блок с `email.blur` находится.... предположу что он находится в каком нибудь блоке а-ля `$("selector").click(function(){`

Comment: `mailgun_validator` - асинхронная функция, просто не успевает вернуть ответ сразу

Comment: без указания, что за библиотека используется сложно сказать.  стоить добавить  [mcve] Возможно первый вызов не делает валидацию, а инициализирует объект. Даже скорее всего.

Comment: Если код обернут только в `$(document).ready(function () { });` то откуда берется `email` ?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать _желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код_ для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. Добавьте в вопрос [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы перепутали инициализацию валидатора и его вызов.

Вынесите вызов инициализации валидатора

```
$('#email').mailgun_validator({
    api_key: 'key',
    in_progress: validation_in_progress, // called when request is made to validator
    success: validation_success,         // called when validator has returned
    error: validation_error,           // called when an error reaching the validator has occured
});
```

из обработчика `blur`.

Comment: если я вас правильно понял, то инициализация происходит не в blur а вот вызов пользовательской функции как раз внутри?

Comment: @Vadim.K, да, подозреваю все обработчики библиотека навешивает сама, поэтому достаточно просто вызвать инициализацию, все остальное она сделает сама. В то время как пользовательская функция - обычная функция которая просто проверяет значение